# Why are there no Micro USB to Micro USB cables?

Tags: usb, cable

Well, it's not like there are not. I found only 1 website selling micro usb to micro usb cables. But it seems they solder them themselves.

So why it is so difficult to get them?

Comment: The micro USB spec (linked from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_usb#cite_note-MicroUSB_1.01-36)) specifies A (host side) and B (client/peripheral side) plugs, but only B receptacles (i.e. your phone) and "AB" receptacles. The latter are restricted to "On The Go" devices, defined as "A device with the host and peripheral capabilities". AFAICT, there's simply no need for these cables, as long as you don't want to plug your camera into your phone. Computers are prohibited from having micro USB ports AFAICT. (Just looked this up, so it might well be wrong).

Comment: This ought to change as more devices add support (notably the Nexus 4 said it would support USB OTG). But at the moment USB on mobile is really only available on Win8 tablets, which use fullsize USB anyway.

Comment: Connecting a mobile phone to an e-bike computer typically requires this type of cable.

Comment: I encountered this in a Kiosk terminal.

Internally there is a small PCB functioning as a USB hub having:
• 1x USB-A female connector for a USB NFC reader with a male USB-A plug 
• 1x USB-Micro female connector for getting USB-power 
• 1x USB-Micro female connector which routes this to a Tablet with a female USB-Micro connector. For this connection a male USB-Micro to male USB-Micro cable is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is likely for the same reason that USB A-to-A cables aren't common: host devices should always use different connectors than slave devices. The reason is that serious damage to the USB controller is possible if you plug two ends of a USB A-to-A cable to two USB ports on a host device (like into your computer). It is against the spec for a reason.

A-to-A cables (or cables as you describe) should not exist according to the spec, simply put.

Comment: Micro USB has both A and B plugs.

Comment: @DanielBeck It wasn't clear that the question was concerning micro USB A to micro USB B. I interpreted it as A to A.

Comment: "host devices should always use different connectors than slave devices". It's interesting how USB-C took a different stance on this.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is, that devices with a Micro USB connector do not typically offer USB-Host functionality.  So even if you were able to connect two devices with Micro USB ports, there would be no additional benefit/nothing to do with this connection.

But as I said, it is just a guess..

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mcmelectronics.com/product/DISTRIBUTED-BY-MCM-HK-MUS14-/83-11872 Micro-A to Micro-B cables do exist for USB OTG. But I agree, it's very strange that they're so rare, though justified perhaps by the lack of uses for them at the moment (few microusb hosts, like the other answers point out.)